# How to reconstruct given malloc sequence?

Tags: c, algorithm, malloc

The malloc'd 2d array I have to work from is

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

This isn't constructed from a [][] array but rather malloc'd memory separated by printf("\n");

I'd like to manipulate it and make a for loop to traverse through the list so the result is

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 25
```

so the result is

Row 1 * Column 1-4
Row 2 * Column 1-4 ...

Any help would be appreciated, I'm having a brain fart right now (just got out of class)

```
typedef struct array {
    int cols, rows;
    int *arr;
} array;

array mkSum(array node)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= ((node.cols) * (node.rows)); i++) //goes through all 25
    {

        //CODE TO MANIPULATE

    }
    for (i = 0; i < ((node.cols) * (node.rows)); i++) //goes through all 25
    {
        if (i % node.cols == 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf(" %d", node.arr[i]); //prints out elements

    }
    return(node);
}
```

mkSum is called by passing in a pointer to the array which comes in as the one i have to work from (first example)

```
mkSum(array);
```

Comment: `malloc'd memory separated by printf("\n");` Sorry, this makes no sense in `C` speak. Besides, there is no `malloc` in the code you posted thus far. Also `mkSum(array node)` receives an `array` struct by value, not `by passing in a pointer to the array`. You may want to rethink what you are asking, and edit the question so that it actually parses.

Comment: `25` of result maybe `20`

Comment: strongly suggest, do not pass a whole array.  rather pass a pointer to the array,  both for the parameter and for the return type.  I.E. `array * mkSum(array * node)`.  Then expressions like: `(node.cols)` would become: `(node->cols)`

Comment: strongly suggest modifying the code that produces the array to NOT be inserting any newlines.  Then it would actually be a array[4][5] array and would be easy to traverse.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear (in particular about the desired result), but I think for the manipulation you best use two nested loops, and simulate node.arr being a 2d array:

```
for (int col = 0; col < node.cols; col++ ) {
    for (int row = 0; row < node.rows; row ++ ) {
        ... Element to modify: node.arr[row * node.cols + col]
    }
}
```

You'll have to adjust to calculation formula for the fact that row/col starts with 0 in this approach.

Comment: this will fail because the incoming array isn't actually an array but rather groups of 4 entry arrays, separated by newlines.

Comment: Judging from the 'array' definition, and the way the array is printed, what you say is not the case. Of course, we don't see the code creating the array, we have only a vague (and possibly incorrect) description of it.

Comment: per the question, the array is actually in a malloc'd memory area and was created using `printf( ...\n....)'  so the array does contain the newline sequences,  so traversing the array will require skipping over those newline sequences, which the posted answer does not do.

Comment: Neither does the OP's loop to print the matrix "skip newlines", yet seems to be working just fine. "This isn't constructed..." seems to refer to how the preceding output was produced; not to how the matrix array as such was created. You're welcome to disagree, and ultimately only the OP can clarify, but I see no sign in the actual given code that the array contains 'newlines'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int col = 1; col <= node.cols; col++ ) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= node.rows; row ++ ) {

        printf(" %d", col*row);
    }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: this will fail because the incoming array contains excess characters after each group of 4 entries. (the newline sequence)